# Passing Array as argument in form {}

Tags: java

I can set an array like this:

```
Object[] objects = {new Object()};
```

However if I have a method:

```
public void setObject(Object[] objects) {

}
```

I cannot do the following:

```
setObject({new Object()});
```

Why is this? Why doesn't `{new Object()}` suffice as an argument but suffices to initialize an `Object[]` array?

Answer (score 8):

You can pass an anonymous array :

```
setObject(new Object[] { new Object() });
```

Note that the syntax `{ new Object() }` just works when initializing the array on its declaration. For example:

```
Object[] arr = { new Object() };
```

This doesn't work after declaring the array:

```
Object[] arr;
//uncomment below line and you'll get a compiler error
//arr = { new Object() };
arr = new Object[] { new Object() };
```

Comment: Heh, I just solved this problem last week and came up with pretty much the same solution.  I know if it's the 'perfect' answer, but I can assure you it does work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Because you haven't typed the Array.  It could be objects, integers, whatever.

The following should work:

```
setObject(new Object[]{new Object()});
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper callback is:

```
setObject(new Object[]{new Object()});
```

Answer (score 1):

Every Java array has a component type. When used in an initializer, the compiler infers that the type of the new array (the right-hand side) is the same as the declared type (the left-hand side).

When the declaration is missing, the compiler doesn't know what the component type of the array should be. You must be explicit, using the expression `setObject(new Object[] { new Object() })`

One might wonder why the compiler doesn't infer the type from the declared type of the method parameter, like it does when initializing a variable. But, the compiler resolves the method to call based on the parameter types; if you don't know the method you are calling, you can't infer anything from its parameter types. There's no circularity when initializing a variable.