# Should I use `new` with an inline-initialized array?

Tags: java, arrays

As far as I can tell, this code:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2 };
```

is the same as this code:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2 };
```

In fact, the compiled `.class` disassembles to the same code:

```
 1: newarray       int
 3: dup
 4: iconst_0
 5: iconst_1
 6: iastore
 7: dup
 8: iconst_1
 9: iconst_2
10: iastore
11: astore_1
12: iconst_2
```

However, similar code does not always perform the same way, or even compile. For example, consider:

```
for (int i : new int[] { 1, 2 }) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

This code (in a main method) compiles and prints `1 2`. However, removing the `new int[]` to make the following:

```
for (int i : { 1, 2 }) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

generates multiple compile-time errors, beginning with

```
Test.java:3: error: illegal start of expression
for (int i : {1, 2} ) {
             ^
```

I would assume that the difference between these two examples is that in the first example (with `int[] numbers`), the type `int` is explicitly stated. However, if this is the case, why can't Java infer the type of the expression from the type of `i`?

More importantly, are there other cases where the two syntaxes differ, or where it is better to use one than the other?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks for the helpful link. However, I'm not sure that it completely answers the question: namely, are there other cases where the syntaxes differ?

Comment: Check all the answers, not just the top one.

Comment: I assume you're referring to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16697404/732016) by erickson. That answer does explain it for methods, but not for `for` loops, where the type is explicitly stated and there is no risk of circularity.

Comment: As stated there, there's no way the compiler can infer the type of the  array, so you will need an anonymous array i.e. use `new int[]{ <elements> }`.

Comment: How is there no way the compiler can infer the type? What about the declared type of the variable `i`? It's `int` - therefore the following one must be either `int[]` or `Iterable<Integer>`, and it clearly can't be the second one. I don't see the ambiguity.

Comment: You can use `int` to traverse a `byte[]` or a `char[]` as well...

Answer (score 2):

From [`JLS #10.6. Array Initializers`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)

> An array initializer may be specified in a declaration (§8.3, §9.3, §14.4), or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10), to create an array and provide some initial values.